# How to set up In-App purchase Free for One Year?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my application, I have to give my app features free for one year but user should be charged for every one year later.
The Auto-Renewable Subscription does not give a Free Trial for one year. The Auto-Renewable Subscription’s max free Trial Duration is 3 Months. I can use this Auto-Renewable Subscription after first year. But for giving free subscription for one year which In-App Purchase type should I use and how to validate user that his one year free subscription has expired?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Non renewing subscriptions for this, and you can handle the date of expiration using a Web Service.
Details on non renewing subscriptions:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial